# What is Hostname Variable Value? when msi editing property table using Orca

Tags: windows-installer, orca

Im trying to modify a msi's property's table to preset values. I am stuck on this last entry that im trying to preset. The property is called MachineID. Im trying to set the value to a variable, like cmd's %computername%.  So that when i run the MSI  in the MachineID field the computername of the computer running this msi is placed in that field. But doesnt seem to be working.  What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What other tables are using the MachineID property?  There is a built in MSI property called ComputerName that you should probably using.  You can also use environment variables by saying [%COMPUTERNAME].    You can't use [%ENVVAR] in the property table itself though because it won't be formatted.  You'd use it in other tables such as the Registry table.  If you really wanted to set MachineID=[%ENVVAR] you'd author a type 51 set property custom action and schedule it appropriately.

Comment: I do see the built in MSI property computername. its set to 0.

Comment: Property names are case sensitive.  ComputerName is not computername.